# Magento 2 : How Can I get All Active Offline Payment Methods?

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, payment, cash-on-delivery, payment-banktransfer

I want to get the list of all active offline payment methods like cashondelivery, checkmo, banktransfer etc.

Comment: did you get any way to list out all active offline payment methods?

Comment: just try with this http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-2-get-payment-methods-all-active-used/

Answer (score 0):

Although the question is very old, but since it has not been answered yet, I would like to answer.

I assume that we need to get the active offline payment methods in a controller file and the controller has been defined in the routes.xml already.

To get the active offline payment methods, we need to first inject the **\Magento\Payment\Helper\Data** class in the constructor and then use the **getPaymentMethods()** function to get all payment methods.

After this the class should look something like this:

```
<?php

namespace {Package}\{Module}\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {

    protected $_paymentHelper;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context, \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentHelper) {
        $this->_paymentHelper = $paymentHelper;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute() {
        $paymentMethods = $this->_paymentHelper->getPaymentMethods();
        if (count($paymentMethods)) {
            foreach ($paymentMethods as $paymentMethod) {
                if (isset($paymentMethod['active']) && $paymentMethod['active'] == 1 && isset($paymentMethod['group']) && $paymentMethod['group'] == 'offline') {
                    echo "<pre>";
                    print_r($paymentMethod);
                    echo "</pre>";
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I hope, this should help.

Help Source: http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-2-get-payment-methods-all-active-used/